# Filtering by JSON type field with Postgres and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgres-9.6

I have a table `test_table`:

```
 Column     |          Type          |
------------+------------------------+
 id         | integer                |
 attributes | json                   |
```

With content:

```
 id |    attributes
----+----------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": ["b1","b2"]}
  2 | {"a": 2, "b": ["b3"]}
  3 | {"a": 3}
```

And I need to filter the data by attribute `b` in the field `attributes`.
I found a solution using the `like` method.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE attributes ->> 'b' SIMILAR TO '%(b1|b3)%';
-- or using SQLAlchemy
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
arr = [f"%{i}%" for i in arr]
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"], String).like(any_(arr)))
```

The result is:

```
 id |    attributes
----+----------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": ["b1","b2"]}
  2 | {"a": 2, "b": ["b3"]}
```

But I am still trying to find a solution like this

```
SELECT * FROM test_table 
WHERE attributes -> 'b' ?| array['b1', 'b3'];
```

Is this possible with pure SQLAlchemy?

Postgres 9.6
SQLAlchemy 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible with pure SQLAlchemy?

It is, pretty much exactly how you pictured it. Cast and use `jsonb` containment: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zq0YIvma)

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_table 
WHERE attributes::jsonb -> 'b' ?| array['b1', 'b3'];
```

In pure SQLAlchemy you can [`cast()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.contains) just the same, and [`?|`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) operator [translates](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/e769ba4b00859ac8c95610ed149da4d940eac9d0/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/json.py#L48) to [`.has_any()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.has_any)

```python
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"],JSONB).has_any(arr))
```

There's [a table with other translations](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/7147#issuecomment-936647041).

[JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/#id-1.11.6.22.5.7) would be more flexible, but while [SQLAlchemy 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.JSONPathType) does support it, your PostgreSQL 9.6 does not - you would need [12.0 or higher](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/#id-1.11.6.22.5.7).

Comment: Thanks! But right now I can only use Postgresql 9.6.

Comment: But this way is working with 9.6.  
`arr = ["b1", "b3"]  
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"],JSONB).has_any(array(tuple(arr))))
`

Comment: @Duncan 
In case my demo link was confusing because it was set to version 16, I fixed it now to use 9.6 - this was meant to work and does seem to work fine on 9.6.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLAlchemy, working with JSON data can be a bit tricky, especially when it comes to querying based on conditions within JSON fields.

If you're using SQLAlchemy 1.4 or later, you can accomplish this as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

# Assuming test_table is your Table object and 'attributes' is the column
stmt = select(test_table).where(
    func.jsonb_exists_any(
        cast(test_table.c.attributes['b'], JSONB),
        array(['b1', 'b3'])
    )
)
```